# Unknown value in milestone payload

Tags: transaction, iota-network, tangle, milestones

I'm exploring the following [milestone message](https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/message/17a2677719744d71c8a13c09660f8a01e33b8d894596c23b32516c7e701d9cd4).

And I'm using the following RFC: [0019-RFC](https://github.com/jakubcech/protocol-rfcs/blob/jakubcech-milestonepayload/text/0019-milestone-payload/0019-milestone-payload.md)

From the message, I've identified almost every element, but there is one that is not referenced in the documentation. The value is after the [milestone essence](https://github.com/jakubcech/protocol-rfcs/blob/jakubcech-milestonepayload/text/0019-milestone-payload/0019-milestone-payload.md#structure).

---

Network Id: `b77f44715e0b3014`

Parents' Length: `06`

Parents:

`22c91093bb85edc93065b937fd1cacf0e3edb4d85090c5ba2d5f01df5e9475e4`
`6ef22c8c2dfdbc64d2e915fdbbf9ee22631d6f38cdbddec9c19dcb225dd59452`
`91a1062313db1a03cb6450f1073e21077b99e8c1dfbfdce07c3960fd399de598`
`a7dc23c0432f3d838df8c2017740db8eff481a654c29a515eb126cbd75a0891c`
`b0f4aefbed43a6b2c7d393ba7ee3c9f77c6e0192f06df01d6448e6eb67a1e513`
`c9801a093f789496f3f1bc20a00714decd60dfd33c598894545bfb09ebfcd358`

Payload length: `bf010000`

Payload Type: `01000000`

Index Number: `2af30300`

Timestamp: `b5f1b06000000000`

Parents' Length: `06`

Parents:

`22c91093bb85edc93065b937fd1cacf0e3edb4d85090c5ba2d5f01df5e9475e4`
`6ef22c8c2dfdbc64d2e915fdbbf9ee22631d6f38cdbddec9c19dcb225dd59452`
`91a1062313db1a03cb6450f1073e21077b99e8c1dfbfdce07c3960fd399de598`
`a7dc23c0432f3d838df8c2017740db8eff481a654c29a515eb126cbd75a0891c`
`b0f4aefbed43a6b2c7d393ba7ee3c9f77c6e0192f06df01d6448e6eb67a1e513`
`c9801a093f789496f3f1bc20a00714decd60dfd33c598894545bfb09ebfcd358`

Inclusion Merkle Root: `0e5751c026e543b2e8ab2eb06099daa1d1e5df47778f7787faab45cdf12fe3a8`

Next PoW Score: `00000000`

Next PoW Score Milestone Index: `00000000`

Keys Count: `02`

Public Keys:

`365fb85e7568b9b32f7359d6cbafa9814472ad0ecbad32d77beaf5dd9e84c6ba`
`a9b46fe743df783dedd00c954612428b34241f5913cf249d75bed3aafd65e4cd`

**Unknown value**: `00000000`

Signatures Count: `02`

Signatures:

`988a5221f5088165699557a8d982d4d3edad8ae23cc8880d0f4d655b876b06080077b0141eb505992d6fda43d1ddf12be4d57ac3e8399f55d55075edadb28804`
`b6858eb8a2b4ecac0ed40f52a250ad008b43fc1e761728a03929590660c4ca7dc6225e9e5bedf429eb82de97e35825be34066aaaf2d452fbc3fd5656b5e1590e`

Nonce: `f12a4f9224499224`

---

Does anybody know what this value means? In the documentation the value before the signatures count value is the public keys array, so I don't know what this `00000000` is.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unknown value is a uint32 used to determine if there is an optional receipt payload as part of the milestone payload. The receipts are for the transactions that were transferred from the legacy network.

If the value is `00000000` then there is no receipt payload included in the milestone, if it has a value of `00000003` the data that follows will be the receipt payload structure.

The RFC that describes the receipt payload can be found here https://github.com/luca-moser/protocol-rfcs/blob/rfc/wotsicide/text/0035-wotsicide/0035-wotsicide.md#receipts

Comment: Thank you Martyn, I've downloaded the message as a JSON file and I saw the `receipt` value as null, so I though that should be the `00000000` but I wanted to confirm it here ;)